# System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am trying to upload video in youtube form my c# project.i got source code from [this link.](https://prakashrthd.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/upload-video-on-youtube-from-asp-net-website/)

But when i try to upload i am getting a exception like this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll but was not handled in user code
>   and the details of the exception shown like this
>
> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Wildlife.wmv'.":"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Wildlife.wmv

my code is like that
here is design page

```
Upload Video:<asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server"  />

       <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
            onclick="btnUpload_Click" /
```

my codebehind code is like that:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    YouTubeRequestSettings setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("prakashtest", "AI39si4EpdRFuvaGm8WNIBIHPmpSfiT7Qmy_WIfhDz3OrLmTwqS0lX_8lcCmBTKq-spys_TfQ8ysWRyg9kB5nFYCifmzgPlFKw", "your_u_tube_username", "your_u_tube_password");
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(setting);

    Video newVideo = new Video();

    newVideo.Title = "My Test Movie";
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
    newVideo.Description = "My description";
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
      YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);




    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName,
    "video/quicktime");
    Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
}
```

I am getting error here `Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);`

how to solve this??

Comment: thanks for the response..can u modify my code please???it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the *filename* of the uploaded file to the `MediaFileSource` constructor. That won't work, especially not once deployed on a web server. It returns only the name of the file the user picked, which will then resolve to a path relative to the starting directory of the web application (being `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\` on IIS Express, `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\` on IIS).

Either pass the `MediaFileSource` a stream to the uploaded file if it supports that (`fileUpload1.UploadedFile.InputStream`), or store the uploaded file temporarily on disk (`fileUpload1.UploadedFile.SaveAs()`), pass *that* path to the constructor and remove the file after uploading.

You also may want to offload the uploading to a separate Windows Service, because now your user has first to wait until the file is uploaded to your webserver, and then wait until your webserver uploads it to YouTube until they get a response.

Using these classes also indicates you're using the deprecated V2 API (the blog is from 2012), [use V3 instead](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3).

Comment: No, your code is not modifyable until it works. You need to redesign it altogether.

Comment: what i have to resign can u tell me indetails..i have paste my video  
here C:\Program Files\IIS Express\ now i am getting this error

Comment: Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

Comment: All your options are explained in my answer. Explaining how to implement each one would be too broad.

Comment: ist one  what is meaning of this line???newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
      YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

Comment: No, I'm not going to explain some code you found on a blog from 2012 line by line, I'm sorry. Read the last link in my answer. Use the V3 API.

Comment: what is YouTubeRequestSettings setting = new YouTubeRequestSettings("prakashtest", "AI39si4EpdRFuvaGm8WNIBIHPmpSfiT7Qmy_WIfhDz3OrLmTwqS0lX_8lcCmBTKq-spys_TfQ8ysWRyg9kB5nFYCifmzgPlFKw", "your_u_tube_username", "your_u_tube_password");